# video = torch.tensor(video) RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of NoneType

Tags: python, torch, torchvision, pytorch-dataloader

I faced an issue in my code it was working well fristly then arise an issue with some files, I do not know what is the problem. This error arise in both my local machine and colab enviroment. Can anyone help to fix it and ilstrate to me why this problem arsers

This is output error

```
The detector is retinaface
/content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_new/Politics_news_11_125.mp4
this is data_filename : Politics_news_11_125.mp4
this is dst_filename : /content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Politics_news_11_125.mp4
video resolution: 154  x  154
video framerate: 25.0
video frame count: 16
video duration: 0.64
The landmarks was saved to /content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Politics_news_11_125.mp4
torch.Size([16, 96, 96, 3])
The mouth images have been cropped and saved to /content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Politics_news_11_125.mp4
torch.Size([16, 96, 96, 3])
/content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Politics_news_11_125.mp4
The npz have been saved to /content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Politics_news_11_125.mp4
/content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_new/Politics_news_26_p2_98.mp4
this is data_filename : Politics_news_26_p2_98.mp4
this is dst_filename : /content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Politics_news_26_p2_98.mp4
video resolution: 128  x  132
video framerate: 25.0
video frame count: 23
video duration: 0.92
The landmarks was saved to /content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Politics_news_26_p2_98.mp4
torch.Size([23, 96, 96, 3])
The mouth images have been cropped and saved to /content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Politics_news_26_p2_98.mp4
torch.Size([23, 96, 96, 3])
/content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Politics_news_26_p2_98.mp4
The npz have been saved to /content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Politics_news_26_p2_98.mp4
/content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_new/Morning_program_2_p1_569.mp4
this is data_filename : Morning_program_2_p1_569.mp4
this is dst_filename : /content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Morning_program_2_p1_569.mp4
video resolution: 172  x  154
video framerate: 25.0
video frame count: 10
video duration: 0.4
The landmarks was saved to /content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark/Morning_program_2_p1_569.mp4
Error executing job with overrides: ['data_dir=/content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_new', 'dst_dir=/content/drive/MyDrive/LRWAR_20_retinaface_landmark']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Visual_Speech_Recognition_for_Multiple_Languages/crop_mouth.py", line 125, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/hydra/main.py", line 94, in decorated_main
    _run_hydra(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 394, in _run_hydra
    _run_app(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 457, in _run_app
    run_and_report(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 223, in run_and_report
    raise ex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 220, in run_and_report
    return func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 458, in <lambda>
    lambda: hydra.run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/hydra/_internal/hydra.py", line 132, in run
    _ = ret.return_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/hydra/core/utils.py", line 260, in return_value
    raise self._return_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/hydra/core/utils.py", line 186, in run_job
    ret.return_value = task_function(task_cfg)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Visual_Speech_Recognition_for_Multiple_Languages/crop_mouth.py", line 116, in main
    data = dataloader.load_data(data_filename, landmarks)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Visual_Speech_Recognition_for_Multiple_Languages/pipelines/data/data_module.py", line 37, in load_data
    video = torch.tensor(video)
RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of NoneType
```

this is github of project with simple modification i did it on my local machine

[enter link description here](https://github.com/mpc001/Visual_Speech_Recognition_for_Multiple_Languages)